# JPanel setbounds

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, setbounds

I'm trying to add a `JPanel` to another `JPanel`, and placing it in a specific location on the first `JPanel`. I'm doing this with `setBounds(x, y, w, h)`. Now I know I shouldn't do this, but I need a way to move it around (as an animation).

The problem I'm having is that the Y does not work. If I do `getBounds()` it is set to the correct value, but it doesn't move on the screen. I do have the `Layout` set to `null`.

First `JPanel`:

```
public WarehousePanel()
{
    super(null);

    gantries = new Gantry[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < gantries.length; i++)
    {
        gantries[i] = new Gantry(3);
        add(gantries[i]);
        System.out.println(gantries[i].getY());
        gantries[i].setBounds(15 * (i + 1), 100, 10, 50);
        System.out.println(gantries[i].getBounds());
    }
}'
```

Second `JPanel`:

```
public Gantry(int y)
{
    this.y = y;

    packageY = new ArrayList();

    setBackground(Color.red);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 50));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gantries[i].setBounds(15 * (i + 1), 100, 10, 50);` Y isn't changing.

Comment: Correct, Y on screen still appears to be 5.

Comment: I meant I don't see you're moving Y coordinate. Also if you wanna see animation, you may need to add delay like Thread.sleep(milliseconds). If you don't add delay, you ll only see the last value - you won't see changing values inside for loop. Your screen only rendered jframe after the loop.

Comment: If you're trying to do 2D graphics, it may be worth looking into java2D/Graphics2D: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/. Depending on what you're trying to do it may be more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, but what this code is trying to do is just place the `JPanel`. It's for initializing. But if this part does not work, the animation (which still needs to be programmed) won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps consider using an undecorated [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)? that will do what you want it to do with a lot less fuss. also, it's generally considered a bad idea to use setBounds instead of a layout manager.

if you are absolutely positively are determined to do things this way, then are you sure you're calling the component class's repaint method [as per spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)?

lastly, are you sure the parent JPanel's size is large enough to accommodate the setBounds call on the child component?

Answer (score 0):

> Correct, Y on screen still appears to be 5.

This tells me you are still using the default FlowLayout for the panel.

> If I do getBounds() it is set to the correct value,rk.

yes but you are displaying the value right after you assign the value. That won't tell you anything. You need to display the bounds AFTER the frame is visible. Making the frame visible will invoke the layout manager.

So double check to make sure you are using a null layout.

If that doesn't help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. So create a JFrame and set the layout to null. Then create a JPanel, set its bounds and background and add the panel to the frame. Prove to yourself the basic code works. Then determine what is different from the working code and your code.